# Return title for a particular post via a get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, how can I search through the database and grab the post_id in the screenshot below, then return the meta value for it? I then want to grab the post title for that meta value.

I've tried the following but this doesn't seem to echo out anything:

```
$args = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'tribe_eddticket',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'p' => $item['id'],
'meta_query' => array(
array(
    'key' => '_tribe_eddticket_for_event'
)
)
)); 

foreach ($args as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
    echo $post->post_title;
} 
wp_reset_query();
```

This is my postmeta table in the database:

[image]

It's essentially what the second poster on this forum is saying - https://tri.be/support/forums/topic/event-title-on-checkout-page/

Comment: You should globalize your `$post` variable first, i.e. `global $post;` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the wordpress function get_the_title()

```
foreach ($args as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);
    echo get_the_title($post['post_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($post)
```

and check the array first is it a object type or normal array

if its a normal so try this

```
echo $post['post_title'];
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Can it not be done with the query I have?